# waits for async data in AngularJS or Javascript (Browser)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, odoo

I'm writing a Service Wrapper in AngularJS for Odoo Server, which has all the methods that the server supports and return a **deferred promise** when the service is call. E.g.:

```
$scope.runRPC = function(){
    odooSvc.fields_get('res.users').then(
        function(result){
            console.log(result); //return a list of users 
        }
    );
}
```

However, I need it to be synchronous, and here a reason why.

In Odoo, it has its own JSON rpc API, which has several methods that depend on each other.

For example,

search_read: give u a list of everything on the model u query on
fields_get: give u the list of fields the model has
and much more.

Usually in a working application, we need to call 2 or more API methods to get the final data we want. However, because in Java, everything works asynchronously.The code I image would be nesty and complicated.

So when I make each API calls the depends on one another. it would look like this:

```
$scope.setLoginToContactEmail = function(){
    odooSvc.search_read('res.users').then(
        function(users){
            for(var i=0; i < user.length; i++){
                user = users[0];
                login = user.login
                partner_id = user.partner_id

                odooSvc.read_model('res.partner', partner_id).then(
                    function(partner){
                        if(login === partner.email){
                            odooSvc.write_model('res.partner', partner_id, {email: login}).then(function(msg){
                                console.log(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                )
            }           
        }
    );
}
```

Vs if I could get those API run synchronously or awaits for the data to arrived before I proceed on another call. it would look more simple:

```
$scope.setLoginToContactEmail = function(){
    var users = odooSvc.search_read('res.users');
    for(var i=0; i < user.length; i++){
        user = users[0];
        login = user.login
        partner_id = user.partner_id

        partner = odooSvc.read_model('res.partner', partner_id);
        if (login === partner.email){
            odooSvc.write_model('res.partner', partner_id, {email: login});
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why tagging it with `async-await` if you're not using it? it is possible with Typescript or Babel. It is not possible with plain JS.

Comment: I'm typing it because I'm looking for solution for async-wait in angularJS1. Is there any good examples of Typescript(I know it is used in angularJS2), and babel to be integrated with angularJS1

Comment: @GavinYap: Sure, just use async-await and transpile it with babel. Not sure what kind of "integration" you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jBF0IV4et3FsQOJEQwDd?p=preview) that takes care for Babel transpilation:

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AsyncController">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </body>
```

---

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('AsyncController', ['$timeout', '$scope', async function ($timeout, $scope) {
  $scope.message = 'no timeout';  

  $scope.message = await $timeout(() => 'timeout', 2000);
  $scope.$apply();
}]);
```

`async...await` is as simple as that in TypeScript and ES.next. Two things here should be noticed.

The first one is `this` context inside async controller - it may differ from what is expected. This may not be a problem when classes are used and async methods are bound if necessary. This is a problem for non-OOP code when constructor function is async and cannot reach its `this` right from the start.

Another one is that `async...await` is powered by native Promises. This means that `$scope.$apply()` should be called to trigger digest cycles, despite the fact that digest-friendly `$timeout` has been used.

Answer (score 1):

Async is better than sync.

However, callbacks can become very messy, so we have promises. However, promises can also become messy, although not quite as bad. Async-await is the best way to get sync-looking async code, but you have to transpile. It depends how much tooling you want to use.

Here is how I would write your ES5 code (without starting a new line after `.then(`, which reduces the indents a bit, and I also made some changes in the for loop as I wasn't sure what you meant):

```
$scope.setLoginToContactEmail = function () {
    odooSvc.search_read('res.users').then(function (users) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i]
            var login = user.login
            var partner_id = user.partner_id

            odooSvc.read_model('res.partner', partner_id).then(function (partner) {
                if (login === partner.email) {
                    odooSvc.write_model('res.partner', partner_id, { email: login }).then(function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

With ES6 and the proposal for async functions that can become:

```
$scope.setLoginToContactEmail = async function () {
    const users = await odooSvc.search_read('res.users')
    for (let user of users) {
        const { login, partner_id } = user
        const partner = await odooSvc.read_model('res.partner', partner_id)
        if (login === partner.email) {
            const msg = await odooSvc.write_model('res.partner', partner_id, { email: login })
            console.log(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

It depends on how much transpiling you want to do. Personally, I would adopt part of ES6 (let/const, destructuring, arrow functions, template strings, modules, unicode improvements, spread operator / rest parameters, improved object literals, and possibly class literals), the stuff that you use most frequently / isn't too difficult to transpile. Maybe also use async-await: it's not a part of ES6 or ES2016, but it is at stage 3 now so it is pretty stable, and it does make async code a lot easier to read. The caveat is that you have to transpile new ES6/ES2016/etc. features using [Babel](http://babeljs.io) or [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org), and use a polyfill for promises (which async-await uses internally).

**TL;DR: if you find yourself descending into async hell, the async-await proposal is probably the best solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous methods are the power of JavaScript which we must be utilized. And the reason is, if the task will take so long time to execute then we do not have to wait and meanwhile can put other task in execution.

We can see its advantage over the UI where we can put long taking time task in the callback and can avoid to UI be grayout.
So I would suggest to adopt aync approach.

But the way you are deciding the execution of the methods is not the better way in Angular way.

Angular has provided you $q.when(method()).then(successCallback(response));, through it control would come in successCallback only when method() execution is done and method() response can be used to make another promise call. This approach would help you to reduce the complexity of the code because you tried to make the chain of callbacks which is not correct conventionally.

```
$scope.setLoginToContactEmail = function(){
    $q.when(searchRead()).then(function(res) {
        modelRead(res);
    });
}


function searchRead() {
    odooSvc.search_read('res.users').then(
            // @TODO       
        }
    );

}

function modelRead(res) {
    odooSvc.read_model('res.partner').then(
                    // @TODO
                )
}
```